# How to test value during the method execution and after the method execution

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I need to test the audit boolean value during execution of method and after execution of method.
While method is invoked Audit value should be true and once method execution is completed the value should be false.

Code i am aware of need to know what annotation or code should i write to test the value during execution of method.

Java code:

```
public TestEntity testCheck(@PathVariable("testKey"))
{
    request.validate("Controller.manage");
    Account response = operation.execute(testKey);
   // need to check if audit value is true during execute method is running 
    return new TestEntity(responseResource, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Need to check if audit value is true during execute method is running

Once this is invoked Audit value should be FALSE.

```
AuditCheck.getAuditEnabledForTest().equals(true);
```

After operation is done it should be

```
AuditCheck.getAuditEnabledForTest().equals(false);
```

Comment: You want to create Unit test?

Comment: Yes, test case for checking value during execution of operation.execute() .. Not before nor after.